# Is there a way to disable the initialization timer in Office.js?

Tags: office-js

We came across an issue when testing our Office.js add-in under poor network conditions. The following error is thrown even before our script is loaded:
`Uncaught Office.js has not been fully loaded yet. Please try again later or make sure to add your initialization code on the Office.initialize function.`

After debugging for hours we found the following piece of code in `Office.js`:

```
g.waitForFunction(function() {
    return Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.initialize != undefined
}, function(a) {
    if (a) {
        if (h.prepareApiSurface)
            Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.initialize(h.getInitializationReason(b));
        else
            h.prepareRightBeforeWebExtensionInitialize(b);
        h.prepareRightAfterWebExtensionInitialize && h.prepareRightAfterWebExtensionInitialize()
    } else
        throw "Office.js has not been fully loaded yet. Please try again later or make sure to add your initialization code on the Office.initialize function."
}, 400, 50)
```

The `waitForFunction` method takes 4 parameters:
`function` - State check function that returns a boolean.
`function` - Callback function called when the state check function returns `true` or the method fails.
`Number` - Number of retries.
`Number` - Milliseconds between tries.

Based on the source code we found, an Office add-in has ~20 seconds to initialize before the framework times out and simply gives up. This is specially problematic on Office 365 online and slow connections.

The following add-in reproduces the issue:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Test Init</title>
    <script src="//appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="ms-font-l" style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
<div id="app" style="height:100%"></div>
<script>
    console.log('Our script loaded...');
    setTimeout(function () {
        Office.initialize = function () {
            console.log('Our App Initialized!!!')
        };
    }, 15000);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

My question is, is there a way to bypass this timeout? or at least increase it? Maybe use something like:
`Office.initialize(function() { /* ... */ });`
rather than:
`Office.initialize = function() { /* ... */};`

If not, would the office team consider changing the timer to instead use a property:

```
Object.defineProperty(Office, 'initialize', {
    get: function() { return Office._initialize; },
    set: function(value) { Office._initialize = value; Office.triggerCodeDependantOnInitialize(); }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There currently is no way to avoid the timeout. That said, you should always call Office.initialize before anything else is executed. In general my guidance is to place this call at the bottom on your HEAD.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Test Init</title>
    <script src="//appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
    <script>
        Office.initialize = function () {
            console.log('Office Initialized!!!')     

        };
    </script>
</head>
```

I then use an event to trigger any additional initialization code I need when the document is ready (i.e. `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){ })` or JQuery's `$(document).ready`)